# Como executar uma ação ao terminar o each() JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loop

Estou usando a função `each()` do **JQuery** gostaria de saber se existe um mecanismo para que eu possa executar uma função depois que terminar o `each()`.

Assim que terminar minha `each()`, já possa fazer outra coisa, mas assim não funcionou.

```
$(".budgetSelectedNumber").each(function () {
       let value = Number($(this).val());
       arrayProductSelecteds.push(value)
}).done(function(){
       console.log("finish")
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).each(...).done is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A execução do código só prossegue após a finalização do `$.each()`. Ou seja, a próxima linha após o `$.each()` só será executada quando o `$.each()` finalizar:

```
$(".budgetSelectedNumber").each(function () {
    let value = Number($(this).val());
    arrayProductSelecteds.push(value);
});

console.log("O each terminou!");
```

Então não precisa de nenhuma função específica ou um callback pra isso, até porque ele não possui ([veja a documentação](https://api.jquery.com/each/)).

Comment: Pensei que o meu problema era no each() mas você ta certo, obrigado.